# Linq to select rows with all included flags and no excluded flags

Tags: c#, linq

I have attribute flags that can be applied to many IDs via a many to many join table:

```
ID | Flag
---------
1  | C
2  | B
3  | B
3  | C
4  | A
5  | A
5  | C
6  | A
6  | B
7  | A
7  | B
7  | C
```

This pivots to:

```
1   C
2  B
3  BC
4 A
5 A C
6 AB
7 ABC
```

Given 2 flag arrays, Include and Exclude I want to find all IDs that have all of the Include flags and none of the Exclude flags.

Include = [A, B], Exclude = [C]: result ID = [6]

Include = [A], Exclude = [C]: result ID = [4, 6]

Include = [A], Exclude = []: result ID = [4, 5, 6, 7]

I want this in Linq, ideally this should be using query syntax.

I've tried creating this but can't get over how to start treating multiple entries with one set of criteria.

```
from row in data
where 
    include.Contains(row.Flag) &&
    !exclude.Contains(row.Flag)
select row.ID
```

Comment: I see several `I want`s and nothing related to `I tried`.

Comment: What you mean by saying Include, exclude? I don't get you... ;( Do you wnat to pass two parameters to linq query: Include A,B &&  Exclude D then ID = 6?

Comment: @Jonesy my very simple linq fell flat on its face, i.e. included any and excluded none, and tried working through it in SQL which usually helps, but couldn't get my head round it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dictionary<int, string> flags = new Dictionary<int, string> { /* ... */ };
string[] includes = ["A", "B"];
string[] excludes = ["C"];
flags
    .GroupBy(f => f.Id)
    .Where(g =>
        includes.All(i => g.Any(f => f.Flag == i)) &&
        !excludes.Any(e => g.Any(f => f.Flag == e)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to group by `ID`, then check if each group contains all `Include` flags and none of the `Exclude` ones:

```
var q = Items.GroupBy(x => x.ID)
             .Where(g => (g.Select(x => x.Flag)
                           .Intersect(Include)
                           .Count() == Include.Count()) 

                         &&                        
                         (g.Select(x => x.Flag)
                           .Intersect(Exclude)
                           .Count() == 0))
             .Select(g => g.Key);
```

I am using `Intersect` to check existence / non-existence of `Include` / `Exclude` flags within each group.

Given your sample data and, e.g.:

```
string[] Include = new string[] { "A", "B" };
string[] Exclude = new string[] { "C" };
```

output is:

```
[0] = 6
```

`Items` object used in above linq query is a `List` of:

```
class Item
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Flag { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Also works https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZstMV8, but pluc's was first and is  shorter.